# Mobile browser and google apps in mobile internet fails to connect, but everything else can use connection

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, mobile-network

My android phone cannot browse any internet page and use google apps on 2G/3G network.

However I can freely ping anything from terminal emulator. I can use at as AP point (I am doing it now). Wifi browsing works well. Why I have no idea.

Only indication of problem is:
failed to identify at proxy error (I am not sure my localisation says something similar). What is happening?

I recently installed cyanogenmod instead of Android jelybean 4.1. I cleaned phone using standart procedure through clockwork rom manager.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Yupp. Time settings usually – at least when it only affects secured sessions. Is your phone's date+time set correctly, or is it e.g. back to 2011 or forward to 2525?

Comment: Time settings are correct, but certification might be wrong, I will try to see if it is wrong.